# rxjs operator not working with angular2

Tags: angular, rxjs

I noticed in my angular app that rxjs operators, like `switchMap`, `map` etc, were not working. (My IDE also gives a hint about that.) To be sure, I ran the following code. If I replace `switchMap` with `subscribe`, I do see 'value returned' in the console.

Any idea why the operators are not working?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-2',
    template: `
    <h2>{{title}}</h2>
    `,
})
export class Page2Component implements OnInit{
    title = 'Page2';

    ngOnInit() {
        let obs = new Observable(observable  => {
            observable.next('value returned');
        });
        obs.switchMap(console.log);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to "fire" an observable you need to subscribe to it. Otherwise they will stay "cold".

> The Subscribe operator is the glue that connects an observer to an Observable. In order for an observer to see the items being emitted by an Observable, or to receive error or completed notifications from the Observable, it must first subscribe to that Observable with this operator.
>
> An Observable is called a “cold” Observable if it does not begin to emit items until an observer has subscribed to it; an Observable is called a “hot” Observable if it may begin emitting items at any time, and a subscriber may begin observing the sequence of emitted items at some point after its commencement, missing out on any items emitted previously to the time of the subscription.

Ref: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribe.html

Comment: You don't necessarily need to call `subscribe` to emit values when you call any of the operators like `switchMap`.
http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-switchMap

Comment: @Naveed As I've said in my answer if you don't subscribe to an observable, it will stay cold, it won't have a connection with its observer. Hence, you won't be able to "observe" anything. Check the example in the link you have given. I admit using emit in that documentation is a bit confusing but `switchMap` just maps/emits these values to observables but if these observables don't have observers, you can't see/observe anything.

Comment: Ok. I got that. `switchMap` and `map` return another observable that I need to subscribe to.

Comment: e.g. Following worked for me:
        `let obs = new Observable(observable  => {`
        `observable.next('value returned');`
        `});`
        `let obs2 = obs.map((value) => \`${value} mapped!\`);`
        `obs2.subscribe(console.log);`

Comment: @Naveed Glad you figured it out :)